# How to change the colors of the formulae and parentheses in Excel?

Tags: excel, colors, formula

I am using the latest version of Windows 10 and MS Office/Excel. When I would write formulae into a cell, something like "=DEGREES(ACOS(SUM(A1:A2)))", the parentheses would show up as the normal black, red, green, blue as well as the cell reference A1:A2. Now, the colors have changed to cyan, salmon, neon green, and lavender. I haven't found any settings for Excel that could change this, including the themes section of the Page Layout tab and the Accessibility settings. Microsoft Support was useless, took 45 minutes for them to send me to Enterprise Support which wasn't useful because I am not the admin on my account (bought it discounted through my university). Obviously a Google search wasn't helpful either. Thank you for any help.